# How to get my previous value on sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I will try to explain this as best as I can. 
I'm trying to do a program where a person uses a card, and it registers the time when she does that.

I used the following code to determinate the hour of the last time a person uses the card:

```
UPDATE cartao SET horaSaida = CURTIME() WHERE cartao.idCartao = 1
```

So at the moment when I use the card both `horaEntrada` and `horaSaida` have the same value. I need to turn `horaEntrada` to have the value of the first time a person used the card. I tried to use `CASE` but I didn't do much with it, because if it is a logical problem, I don't understand it.

Comment: Well set `horaEntrada` first(exactly like above) when the person uses the card for the first time, and the second time the person uses the card you onlyset `horaSalida`. Or maybe I did not understand the question.

Comment: Yes, now I think I know how to do it. I'm gonna try it now, I say if it is resolved or not after. @IrinaAvram

Comment: You may also want to have a look at [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) of the MySQL docs, where uses like yours are discussed extensively. And, believe me, no need for CASE...WHEN here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can take make three columns (horaEntrada,horaSaida) in table "cartao".

for the first time person uses the card you have to insert the row like this

```
insert into cartao (horaEntrada,horaSaida) values (CURTIME(),CURTIME());
```

when user uses it second time you have to update only "horaSaida" column

```
UPDATE cartao SET horaSaida = CURTIME() WHERE cartao.idCartao = person ID;
```

so that "horaEntrada" will have the firt time and "horaSaida" have the last time.

Comment: I already had both `horaEntrada` and `horaSaida` with the same values. The problem was how to change `horaEntrada` to the first value it had, or don't change it. Like should I use `CASE` or other thing? But now I think I know how to do it, thanks @vishu .

Comment: can u xplain a little more what you exactly want

Comment: I want `horaEntrada` to be for example 10:00am the first time I use the card. And `horaSaida` to be 12:00am the second time. And right now I tried to make this code work: 
`CASE

   WHEN 'horaEntrada'=0 THEN 'horaEntrada' = CURTIME() WHERE 'cartao'.'idCartao' = '$id'

   ELSE 'horaSaida' = CURTIME() WHERE 'cartao'.'idCartao' = '$id'

END`
But it is giving me an error at `CASE` (Unrecognized statment type.[Near `CASE`]).

Comment: this is for day wise or one time entry and you have update only horaSaida

Comment: It's for day wise, but now I'm not focusing on that. I update `horaEntrada` in another php.file that is executed when the cards are used. So I have both variables working.

Comment: you can update both column when u r inserting the row and for update u can only update "horaSaida" column after that it will mark.

Comment: Ok I did that, but the code is giving me a syntax error, why?  `INSERT INTO 'cartao' (horaEntrada,horaSaida) VALUES (CURTIME(),CURTIME()) WHERE 'idCartao'='$id'`
The $id is a POST variable.  @vishu

Comment: can u give me error what is the error coming, try to insert directly by giving any id instead of $id and if that work than your $id constant is not resolving